# JSON Files old data overwritten when opening a new connection c#

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I have a c# WPF Solution. The solution needs to add an object to a JSON file. Which works. The problem i have is when opening a new connection to the file the old data is overwritten. What am i missing? why does it overwrite the old data. am pretty sure it's something simple. but i just can't see it.

```
if (clickCount == 1)
{
    //changes create button text
    createBtn.Content = "Create";
    //creates new message obj
    Message message = new Message();

     //depending on the form type creates a json object
     if (valid.MessageType == "E")
     {
         //checks e-mail
         valid.CheckEmail(senderTxtBox.Text);
         //creates varibles for adding to JSON file
         message.MessageId = messageTypeComboBox.Text + messageTypeTxtBox.Text;
         message.SenderTxt = senderTxtBox.Text;
         message.Subject = subjectTxtBox.Text;
         message.MessageTxt = messageTxtBox.Text;
      }

      messageList.Add(message);

      String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageList, Formatting.Indented);
      System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"JsonMessage.Json", json);

      clickCount = 0;

      messageTxtBox.Clear();
      senderTxtBox.Clear();
      subjectTxtBox.Clear();
      messageTxtBox.Clear();
      messageTypeTxtBox.Clear();
      messageTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using WriteAllText, which will rewrite the file every time you want to transmit a new Json object to your json file.

File.AppendText seems like a better solution, since you would not need to actually rewrite all the file, whenever a new message is added to your MessageList, but would also solve your existing problem when you open a new connection to the file not having all the previously inserted json data deleted.

PS. If you use AppendText, you  will have to pass to the file all your collection, but only the message that you just received, otherwise you would have your file constantly being written with duplicated data and the situation would only get worse with the increase in size of your message list object.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've used the WriteAllText method to write the json to the file.

You should use `AppendText` method instead.

Something like this

```
using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(@"JsonMessage.Json"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(json);
 }
```

Here's a link for more information on File.AppendText

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx